# Excel- Regroup Letter Score

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there any way for me to group Grade Letter as H Column?

[image]

Comment: Your question makes no sense. Column F is a number. Please reword your question to give a more specific explanation of your problem. If writing in English is an issue then consider using Google Translate and writing in your native language and then proof read before posting here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is to use `COUNTIF()` twice:

```
=COUNTIF(B1:G1;"A")&"(A)"&COUNTIF(B1:G1;"B")&"(B)"
```

This can easily be expanded as needed.

[image]

EDIT:
Add `IF()` so that if no grade is present then no grade is shown:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B1:G1;"A")>0;COUNTIF(B1:G1;"A")&"(A)";"")&IF(COUNTIF(B1:G1;"B")>0;COUNTIF(B1:G1;"B")&"(B)";"")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Mr kevin..if there are many students..and A,B grade located randomly..the formula cannot be use right? I am sorry..my explanation not clear. Will update the picture soon.

Comment: Assuming the students grades are listed on one line then simply adjust the range (B1:G1) to suit your dataset. Dragging down will work for more students. Note that where I have used a ; you might need a ,

Comment: Hi Kevin, Working perfectly well..just the result will be like this :   
ryan A A A = 3(A)0(B)

Can u help me so that it become like :
ryan ryan A A A = 3(A)

Just remove the grade that 0 count.
Tq man

Comment: Edited my answer to include an IF(). There is almost certainly a better way to do this but as your grades will (probably) only go to an F this way will do.

Comment: HI @kevin..the formula is error...i am sorry..can u check it?

Comment: The error is the one with “IF”. And can u put space beetween Grade letter, like 2(A) 1 (B) not   2(A)1(B). Thank you man!!

Comment: Hi Cliffe, the formula works. Have you remembered to replace the ; with a ,? Also, adding spaces is easy, just add the space within the speech marks :)

Comment: I already done that..but sees not working. I will try again and update u the error if any ya. The error just now is like (formula 1+1 )Thanks man.

Comment: Tq sooo much Kevin. Working Perfectly!! sorry for trouble just now,

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to use an array formula:

[image: Worksheet Screenshot]

Array enter (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) the following formula in `H1` and copy-paste/fill-down into the rest of the column (don't forget to remove the `{` and `}`):

```dart
{=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,IFERROR(1/(1/(COUNTIF(B1:G1,{"A";"B";"C";"D";"E"})))&"("&{"A";"B";"C";"D";"E"}&")",""))}
```

Note that `TEXTJOIN()` is only available in Excel 2016. In earlier versions of Excel, a poly-fill UDF is required. (See [this post](//superuser.com/a/1331555) for a basic one.)

Also note that this formula will correctly only display a particular grade if a student has achieved at least one of them.